# How can I check if a subroutine returns *nothing*

Tags: perl, subroutine

How can I determine that a perl function return `nothing` not even `undef`?

Examples:

```
sub test {
   return;
}
```

or

```
sub test {}
```

The problem is that the curious acting function can also return strings, lists, ... and is a part of a foreign package. So I cannot check with `test() || undef` because empty lists or strings will be overitten with `undef`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can check the "null" value, so I can create an conditional exception?

Comment: There is no way to "return nothing not even undef"*

Comment: Again, 
 
***There is no way to "return nothing not even undef"***. An empty list is an empty list; that is not "nothing", it is information. Returning "nothing" is a bizarre concept that is impossible in every language.

Comment: Returning an empty list means returning without placing anything on the stack. "Returning an empty list" is a metaphor that's synonymous with "returning zero scalars" and "returning nothing".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you use `return` and you specify no return value, the subroutine returns an empty list
>   in list context, the undefined value in scalar context, or nothing in
>   void context.
>
> If no `return` is found and if the last statement is an expression, its
>   value is returned. If the last statement is a loop control structure
>   like a `foreach` or a `while`, the returned value is unspecified. **The
>   empty sub returns the empty list**.

-[perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

In both of your cases it will return empty list. So you cannot distinguish between them.

If I understood you correctly you are trying to avoid empty list being overridden with undef if you do `test () || undef`. But that doesn't matter. In Perl both empty list and undef are considered false.

All of the below evaluate to false

```
0
'0'
undef
''  # Empty scalar
()  # Empty list
('')
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to "return nothing not even undef"*

The subroutine `test` that you describe evaluates to `undef` if you call it as

```
my $ret = test();
```

or an empty list if you call it as

```
my @ret = test();
```

What you do about that depends on what *valid* values your subroutine may return. Is it designed to return a list or a scalar?

Clearly an error condition must be distinct from any valid return value, and a common way is to always return a scalar value, which may be a reference if you need to return multiple values

Suppose you have a trash subroutine that returns a list of all values in a given range

```
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN { require v5.10 }
use feature 'say';

STDOUT->autoflush;

sub range {
    my ($start, $end) = @_;

    return if $end < $start;

    return [ $start .. $end ];
}

my $range = range(1, 3) or die;
say for @$range;

$range = range(10, 1) or die;
say for @$range;
```

#### output

```
1
2
3
Died at E:\Perl\source\twice.pl line 19.
```

The returned value is `undef` if the parameters are bad, and the calling code may use that information as it likes